# C++ copy constructor in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, copy-constructor, virtual-inheritance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
     A(){ cout <<"1";}
     A(const A &obj){cout <<"2";}
};

class B: virtual A
{
public:
    B(){cout <<"3";}
    B(const B & obj):A(obj){cout<<"4";}
};

class C: virtual A
{
public:
   C(){cout<<"5";}
   C(const C & obj):A(obj){cout <<"6";}
};

class D:B,C
{
public:
    D(){cout<<"7";}
    D(const D & obj):C(obj),B(obj){cout <<"8";}
};

int main()
{
   D d1;
   D d(d1);
}
```

I am getting 13571468 as output. But I think that output should be 13572468. Why normal constructor is running instead on of copy constructor of class A?

Comment: Just provide a `virtual ~A()` destructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Hmm, I doubt that's really can be considered a dupe of that.

Comment: http://tpcg.io/oOKrrf
This is the link to the problem,Please edit it and share a link of the modified program.

Comment: It took me a while to notice that it's using virtual inheritance. Very interesting question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code makes a copy of an instance of `D`, invoking its copy constructor.

Your class `D`'s copy constructor only invokes the copy constructors of its `C` and `B`'s superclasses. Because it does not invoke `A`'s copy constructor, it gets default-constructed.

Virtually-inherited classes can be thought of as direct superclasses of the most-derived class. That's what virtual inheritance means. As such, in your instance of `D`, its virtually-inherited `A` is a direct superclass of `D`, and not of `B` or `C`; as such, `B` and `C`'s invocations of `A` copy-constructor is ***not*** invoked.

When you have a virtually-inherited class, all your constructors really have two versions created "behind the scenes": one that's responsible for constructing any virtually-inherited classes, and one that's not. The one that's not does ***not*** call the virtually-inherited classes's constructors.

Comment: Why doesn't C's copy c'tor invoke A's copy c'tor?

Comment: Because it is not responsible for doing so. Only the most-derived class constructs all virtually-inherited superclasses. I amended my answer to explain this. If you copy-construct C, it will do it. But if you copy-construct D, it doesn't do that. D is responsible for constructing A.

Comment: It might be helpful to go into more detail about the fact that there are *two* copy constructors for C - and.

Comment: If I do this D(const D & obj):C(obj),B(obj),A(obj){cout <<"8";}  , then it is giving error. Can you please tell a way to call the base class i.e. A's copy contructor.

Comment: You have to explicitly declare `D` as virtually inheriting from `A`, like all other classes. Then you can invoke its copy constructor. If you don't declare it, it still virtually inherits `A`, of course. But it always uses its default constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SamVarshavchik

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "_You have to explicitly declare D as virtually inheriting from A_" what do you mean?

Comment: Why, `class D:B,C,virtual A { /* with the rest being the same */` of course -- and I'm just curious what would've been more clear to you than "You have to explicitly declare D as virtually inheriting from A, like all other classes".